# MariaDB replication server's SQL Thread stuck at 'Waiting for prior transaction to commit'

Tags: mariadb, master-slave-replication, mariadb-10.6

Replication hangs often at a one Master - One Replica setup.
From processlist the SQL worker threads seems to wait indefinitely with 'Waiting for prior transaction to commit' status.
Once this happens replication is stuck and STOP SLAVE does not work, have to kill manually then works well for few days and issue occurs again.
The queries before Relay_Log_Pos also does not seem out of ordinary (an insert and an update with PK).

MariaDB : v10.6.10

**Processlist**

```
Id      User    Host    db      Command Time    State   Info    Progress
11      system user             NULL    Slave_IO        986857  Waiting for master to send event        NULL    0.000
13      system user             NULL    Slave_worker    57878   Waiting for prior transaction to commit NULL    0.000
14      system user             NULL    Slave_worker    57878   Waiting for prior transaction to commit NULL    0.000
15      system user             NULL    Slave_worker    57878   Waiting for prior transaction to commit NULL    0.000
16      system user             NULL    Slave_worker    57878   Waiting for prior transaction to commit NULL    0.000
18      system user             NULL    Slave_worker    57878   Waiting for prior transaction to commit NULL    0.000
17      system user             NULL    Slave_worker    57878   Waiting for prior transaction to commit NULL    0.000
20      system user             NULL    Slave_worker    57878   Waiting for prior transaction to commit NULL    0.000
21      system user             NULL    Slave_worker    57878   Waiting for prior transaction to commit NULL    0.000
19      system user             NULL    Slave_worker    57878   Waiting for prior transaction to commit NULL    0.000
22      system user             NULL    Slave_worker    57878   Waiting for prior transaction to commit NULL    0.000
23      system user             NULL    Slave_worker    57878   Waiting for prior transaction to commit NULL    0.000
24      system user             NULL    Slave_worker    57878   Waiting for prior transaction to commit NULL    0.000
25      system user             NULL    Slave_worker    57878   Waiting for prior transaction to commit NULL    0.000
26      system user             NULL    Slave_worker    57878   Waiting for prior transaction to commit NULL    0.000
27      system user             NULL    Slave_worker    57878   Waiting for prior transaction to commit NULL    0.000
28      system user             NULL    Slave_worker    57878   Waiting for prior transaction to commit NULL    0.000
29      system user             NULL    Slave_worker    57878   Waiting for prior transaction to commit NULL    0.000
30      system user             NULL    Slave_worker    57879   closing tables  NULL    0.000
31      system user             NULL    Slave_worker    57878   Waiting for prior transaction to commit NULL    0.000
32      system user             NULL    Slave_worker    57878   Waiting for prior transaction to commit NULL    0.000
34      system user             NULL    Slave_worker    57878   Waiting for prior transaction to commit NULL    0.000
33      system user             NULL    Slave_worker    57878   Waiting for prior transaction to commit NULL    0.000
35      system user             NULL    Slave_worker    57878   Waiting for prior transaction to commit NULL    0.000
36      system user             NULL    Slave_worker    57878   Waiting for prior transaction to commit NULL    0.000
37      system user             NULL    Slave_worker    57878   Waiting for prior transaction to commit NULL    0.000
38      system user             NULL    Slave_worker    57878   Waiting for prior transaction to commit NULL    0.000
39      system user             NULL    Slave_worker    57878   Waiting for prior transaction to commit NULL    0.000
40      system user             NULL    Slave_worker    57878   Waiting for prior transaction to commit NULL    0.000
41      system user             NULL    Slave_worker    57878   Waiting for prior transaction to commit NULL    0.000
42      system user             NULL    Slave_worker    57878   Waiting for prior transaction to commit NULL    0.000
43      system user             NULL    Slave_worker    57878   Waiting for prior transaction to commit NULL    0.000
44      system user             NULL    Slave_worker    57878   Waiting for prior transaction to commit NULL    0.000
45      system user             NULL    Slave_worker    57878   Waiting for prior transaction to commit NULL    0.000
46      system user             NULL    Slave_worker    57878   Waiting for prior transaction to commit NULL    0.000
47      system user             NULL    Slave_worker    57878   Waiting for prior transaction to commit NULL    0.000
48      system user             NULL    Slave_worker    57878   Waiting for prior transaction to commit NULL    0.000
49      system user             NULL    Slave_worker    57878   Waiting for prior transaction to commit NULL    0.000
50      system user             NULL    Slave_worker    57878   Waiting for prior transaction to commit NULL    0.000
51      system user             NULL    Slave_worker    57878   Waiting for prior transaction to commit NULL    0.000
52      system user             NULL    Slave_worker    57878   Waiting for prior transaction to commit NULL    0.000
53      system user             NULL    Slave_worker    57878   Waiting for prior transaction to commit NULL    0.000
54      system user             NULL    Slave_worker    57878   Waiting for prior transaction to commit NULL    0.000
55      system user             NULL    Slave_worker    57878   Waiting for prior transaction to commit NULL    0.000
56      system user             NULL    Slave_worker    57878   Waiting for prior transaction to commit NULL    0.000
57      system user             NULL    Slave_worker    57878   Waiting for prior transaction to commit NULL    0.000
58      system user             NULL    Slave_worker    57878   Waiting for prior transaction to commit NULL    0.000
59      system user             NULL    Slave_worker    57878   Waiting for prior transaction to commit NULL    0.000
60      system user             NULL    Slave_worker    57878   Waiting for prior transaction to commit NULL    0.000
12      system user             NULL    Slave_SQL       57999   Waiting for room in worker thread event queue   NULL    0.000
```

**Slave status**

```
Slave_IO_State: Waiting for master to send event
                   Master_Host: a.b.c.d
                   Master_User: repl
                   Master_Port: 3307
                 Connect_Retry: 60
               Master_Log_File: binary-log.024465
           Read_Master_Log_Pos: 312810975
                Relay_Log_File: mysql-1-relay-bin.004631
                 Relay_Log_Pos: 201089830
         Relay_Master_Log_File: binary-log.024265
              Slave_IO_Running: Yes
             Slave_SQL_Running: Yes
               Replicate_Do_DB:
           Replicate_Ignore_DB: mysql
            Replicate_Do_Table:
        Replicate_Ignore_Table:
       Replicate_Wild_Do_Table:
   Replicate_Wild_Ignore_Table:
                    Last_Errno: 0
                    Last_Error:
                  Skip_Counter: 0
           Exec_Master_Log_Pos: 610809588
               Relay_Log_Space: 76470879853
               Until_Condition: None
                Until_Log_File:
                 Until_Log_Pos: 0
            Master_SSL_Allowed: No
            Master_SSL_CA_File:
            Master_SSL_CA_Path:
               Master_SSL_Cert:
             Master_SSL_Cipher:
                Master_SSL_Key:
         Seconds_Behind_Master: 57879
 Master_SSL_Verify_Server_Cert: No
                 Last_IO_Errno: 0
                 Last_IO_Error:
                Last_SQL_Errno: 0
                Last_SQL_Error:
   Replicate_Ignore_Server_Ids:
              Master_Server_Id: 2
                Master_SSL_Crl:
            Master_SSL_Crlpath:
                    Using_Gtid: Current_Pos
                   Gtid_IO_Pos: 0-2-703347858
       Replicate_Do_Domain_Ids:
   Replicate_Ignore_Domain_Ids:
                 Parallel_Mode: optimistic
                     SQL_Delay: 0
           SQL_Remaining_Delay: NULL
       Slave_SQL_Running_State: Waiting for room in worker thread event queue
              Slave_DDL_Groups: 21059
Slave_Non_Transactional_Groups: 0
    Slave_Transactional_Groups: 71502590
```

**Relay log events**

```
show relaylog events in 'mysql-1-relay-bin.004631' from 201088966 limit 20;
+--------------------------+-----------+----------------+-----------+-------------+------------------------------------------+
| Log_name                 | Pos       | Event_type     | Server_id | End_log_pos | Info                                     |
+--------------------------+-----------+----------------+-----------+-------------+------------------------------------------+
| mysql-1-relay-bin.004631 | 201088966 | Xid            |         2 |   610806615 | COMMIT /* xid=33545593056 */             |
| mysql-1-relay-bin.004631 | 201088997 | Gtid           |         2 |   610806659 | BEGIN GTID 0-2-696762571 cid=33545631902 |
| mysql-1-relay-bin.004631 | 201089041 | Table_map      |         2 |   610807665 | table_id: 16927 (aDatabase.table1)           |
| mysql-1-relay-bin.004631 | 201089153 | Write_rows_v1  |         2 |   610807864 | table_id: 16927 flags: STMT_END_F        |
| mysql-1-relay-bin.004631 | 201089352 | Table_map      |         2 |   610809239 | table_id: 101 (aDatabase.table2)       |
| mysql-1-relay-bin.004631 | 201089481 | Update_rows_v1 |         2 |   610809557 | table_id: 101 flags: STMT_END_F          |
| mysql-1-relay-bin.004631 | 201089799 | Xid            |         2 |   610809588 | COMMIT /* xid=33545619314 */             |
| mysql-1-relay-bin.004631 | 201089830 | Gtid           |         2 |   610809632 | BEGIN GTID 0-2-696762572 cid=33545631902 |
| mysql-1-relay-bin.004631 | 201089874 | Table_map      |         2 |   610810941 | table_id: 16924 (aDatabase.table3)       |
| mysql-1-relay-bin.004631 | 201089988 | Write_rows_v1  |         2 |   610811072 | table_id: 16924 flags: STMT_END_F        |
| mysql-1-relay-bin.004631 | 201090119 | Table_map      |         2 |   610823353 | table_id: 16928 (aDatabase.table4)       |
| mysql-1-relay-bin.004631 | 201090240 | Write_rows_v1  |         2 |   610829138 | table_id: 16928 flags: STMT_END_F        |
| mysql-1-relay-bin.004631 | 201096025 | Table_map      |         2 |   610830574 | table_id: 72 (aDatabase.table5)       |
| mysql-1-relay-bin.004631 | 201096152 | Update_rows_v1 |         2 |   610831036 | table_id: 72 flags: STMT_END_F           |
| mysql-1-relay-bin.004631 | 201096614 | Table_map      |         2 |   610832472 | table_id: 72 (aDatabase.table5)       |
| mysql-1-relay-bin.004631 | 201096741 | Update_rows_v1 |         2 |   610832934 | table_id: 72 flags: STMT_END_F           |
| mysql-1-relay-bin.004631 | 201097203 | Table_map      |         2 |   610834371 | table_id: 72 (aDatabase.table5)       |
| mysql-1-relay-bin.004631 | 201097330 | Update_rows_v1 |         2 |   610834833 | table_id: 72 flags: STMT_END_F           |
| mysql-1-relay-bin.004631 | 201097792 | Table_map      |         2 |   610836271 | table_id: 72 (aDatabase.table5)       |
| mysql-1-relay-bin.004631 | 201097919 | Update_rows_v1 |         2 |   610836733 | table_id: 72 flags: STMT_END_F           |
+--------------------------+-----------+----------------+-----------+-------------+------------------------------------------+
20 rows in set (0.078 sec)
```

**Replica my.cnf**

```
binlog-format=ROW
binlog-ignore-db=mysql
binlog-ignore-db=performance_schema
binlog-ignore-db=test
binlog_cache_size=4M
binlog_commit_wait_count=48
binlog_commit_wait_usec=20000
character_set_server=utf8
datadir=/data/mysql-1
expire_logs_days=3
general-log=0
general_log_file=/var/opt/na/log/mysql-1/general-query.log
gtid_strict_mode=1
innodb=FORCE
innodb_buffer_pool_chunk_size=128M
innodb_buffer_pool_size=192G
innodb_data_file_path=ibdata:100M:autoextend
innodb_data_home_dir=/data/mysql-1
innodb_fast_shutdown=1
innodb_file_per_table=1
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=2
innodb_flush_method=O_DIRECT
innodb_force_recovery=0
innodb_io_capacity=3000
innodb_log_buffer_size=8M
innodb_log_file_size=2047MB
innodb_log_group_home_dir=/data/mysql-1
innodb_open_files=10000
innodb_print_all_deadlocks=1
innodb_purge_threads=1
interactive_timeout=420
join_buffer_size=256K
join_buffer_space_limit=2M
join_cache_level=2
log-bin=binary-log.
log-error=/var/opt/na/log/mysql-1/error.log
max_allowed_packet=33554432
max_connections=2300
max_heap_table_size=64M
open-files-limit=65535
optimizer_switch=default
pid-file=/var/opt/na/run/mysql-1.pid
port=3307
query_cache_type=0
replicate-ignore-db=mysql
server-id=1
skip-name-resolve
slave_net_timeout=60
slave_parallel_max_queued=1048576
slave_parallel_mode=optimistic
slave_parallel_threads=48
slow-query-log=0
slow_query_log_file=/var/opt/na/log/mysql-1/slow-query.log
socket=/data/mysql-1/mysql.sock
sql_mode=ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER
sync_binlog=0
sync_master_info=0
sysdate_is_now=TRUE
table_definition_cache=500
table_open_cache=10000
thread_handling=pool-of-threads
tmp_table_size=64M
tmpdir=/data/tmp/mysql-1
transaction-isolation=READ-COMMITTED
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like the bug [MDEV-31427](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-31427) that was fixed in 10.6.11. Recommend 10.6.14+ that was released today.

Note there where a few regressions between 10.6.11 and 10.6.13 that are now fixed so avoid this window of releases.

Comment: You mean v10.6.14 too has regression issues ?

Comment: Not that I know of. I was referring to the 10.6.11-> 10.6.13 window. Better wording welcome